# DFactory start: isQmage : stream is not a Qmage file - Contact Badge not loading

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap, user-profile

I've tried several ways to load contact images into a listview and this class works, if there is an image set in the phone. Since that is often not the case I would like to get the facebook profile picture.

I'm using the following class:

```
public final class QuickContactHelper {

private static final String[] PHOTO_ID_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID
};

private static final String[] PHOTO_BITMAP_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO
};

private final QuickContactBadge badge;

private final String phoneNumber;

private final ContentResolver contentResolver;

private final Context myContext;

public QuickContactHelper(final Context context, final QuickContactBadge badge, final String phoneNumber) {

    this.badge = badge;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    myContext=context;

}

public Bitmap getFacebookPhoto() {
    Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Uri photoUri = null;
    Cursor contact = contentResolver.query(phoneUri,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID }, null, null, null);

    if (contact.moveToFirst()) {
        long userId = contact.getLong(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, userId);

    }
    else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    if (photoUri != null) {
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
                contentResolver, photoUri);
        if (input != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
    } else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
    return defaultPhoto;
}

public void addThumbnail() {

    final Integer thumbnailId = fetchThumbnailId();
    if (thumbnailId != null) {
        final Bitmap thumbnail = fetchThumbnail(thumbnailId);
        if (thumbnail != null) {
            badge.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        } 
    }

}

private Integer fetchThumbnailId() {

    final Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, PHOTO_ID_PROJECTION, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    try {
        Integer thumbnailId = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            thumbnailId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
        }
        return thumbnailId;
    }
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

}

final Bitmap fetchThumbnail(final int thumbnailId) {

    final Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, thumbnailId);
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, PHOTO_BITMAP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

    try {
        Bitmap thumbnail = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final byte[] thumbnailBytes = cursor.getBlob(0);
            if (thumbnailBytes != null) {
                thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(thumbnailBytes, 0, thumbnailBytes.length);
            }
       }

        if (thumbnail == null){
            thumbnail=getFacebookPhoto(); //error: isQmage : stream is not a Qmage file 
        }

        return thumbnail;
    }
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

}

}
```

When trying to retrieve the bitmap with the method getFacebookPhoto(), it gives me the following error and not the profile picture:

```
11-20 11:16:26.591: D/(2383): DFactory start
11-20 11:16:26.591: D/(2383): isQmage : stream is not a Qmage file
```

How do I convert the bitmap into a Qmage file? And does this work for non samsung devices?